# How to use Drupal user_check_password()?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do I actually use user_check_password($password, $account)
this is what I'm trying right now to test it

```
$account = mysqli_query($q,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'admin'");

user_check_password('admin',$account)


if (user_check_password('admin',$account)== true){
    echo"Yes";
}else{
    echo"no";
}
```

But this always says no for some reason how do i actually check the password against the database password?

Answer (score 1):

user_check_passwords first argument is the password string you want to check. Is 'admin' the password string you want to check? In your case you are checking if user 'admin' has the password 'admin'.

Try this.

```
 $account = user_load_by_name('admin');
 if (user_check_password('passwordstring',$account)) {
   print "Yes";
 } else {
   print "No";
 }
```